# jQuery accordion in two columns

Tags: jquery, html, accordion

I am working on jQuery accordion for my project and I don't know how to display in two columns. I like to display this way

```
Slide one        Slide Two
Content          Content 

Slide three      Slide Four
Content          Content
```

My jsFiddle [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmSWz/)

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following modifications seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/dhgfT/

switch `.accordion-menu li` to `display: inline-block` , remove the float, and set width to 45%. This will make the `li` elements line up two per row.

```
.accordion-menu li {
    background: #3cf;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
}
```

Now remove the fixed width from the content div

```
.accordion-menu li div {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #aef;
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
}
```

( also removed the now incongruous border from `accordian-menu` )

Comment: Thanks for your response and I like your work but only one should be slide at a time. Can you help me plz.

Comment: Have you changed regarding my previous comment?

Comment: Ah. To make that work, you'll need to separate your header / panel pairs into two divs, which will be your two columns. You'll need to switch from a `<ul><li>` structure something like `<h1><div>`, adjusting your css appropriately, and change your invocation to something like `$('.pageContent .accordian-menu').accordion({ header: "h1"});` so that the accordian can identify the header / panel pairs even though they are not immediate children ( they will be nested with the columns ) ... if you set up a fiddle sort of like that, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use [jqueryui portlets](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#portlets)
or [jquery grids](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid) as your parnets to do the trick.(ofcourse if got your question the right way)
you can put your accordions in them.

Comment: But this is not I want. Do you have any other example like my question.

Comment: hey dont wast your reputation on down vots! you want accordions on two columns, the way i suggest is using portlets or grids and put accordions in them. ** why down vote?**

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be you can have.. separate div classes and add a style called display:inline-block to it.